# suddenly datetime indexing field selection became longer

Tags: django, postgresql

I have partition table with datetime field indexing
In django orm i have 2 variant of requests

**First variant**

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(my_datetime_field__gt=date(2022, 1 , 1))
```

This request is being made 3.5-5 seconds

**Second variant**

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(my_datetime_field__date__gt=date(2022, 1 , 1))
```

This request is being made 0.05 seconds

**Question**

Previously, requests were completed in the same time. What could have happened?

**Some information**

django: 2.0 
postgres: 12.3 
index_type: btree

**I try next**

VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) my_table 
REINDEX INDEX my_index

Comment: You'll get the answer right away if you use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on both SQL statements.

Comment: Previous to what?  Was there said identifiable change which triggered this?  Do you have a backup from before the behavior change you can restore to a test machine for exploration?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
 
For `date_created__gt` 
Buffers: shared hit=6044199 read=29 I/O Timings: read=0.293
For `date_created__date__gt` 
Buffers: shared hit=217 read=277 I/O Timings: read=35.626
But i dont understand, why for datetime selection used too mach cache

Comment: No. You [edit] the question and add the *complete* plan there, as formatted text.